# Jquery Mobile backbone Select box not showing up

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, routes, handlebars.js, drop-down-menu

I have used Jquery mobile with Backbone and Handlebar i have a select box that loads the country list using the JSON data coming from cakephp and the HTML code is :

```
<select name="Country" id="Country"  data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="all">All Countries</option>
    {{#each output.countries}}
    <option value="{{Country.id}}" >{{Country.name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

But the problem is that the list is too big. so when the browser window size is small jquery mobile tries to open a new page according to :
[jqm docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/custom.html)

But in my case its not opening the page. I debugged the code but it gives me the error in jquery mobile.js version is 1.1.1 in  that on line 3414

```
if ( active.url.indexOf( dialogHashKey ) > -1 && !$.mobile.activePage.is( ".ui-dialog" ) ) {
            settings.changeHash = false;
            alreadyThere = true;
        }
```

this particular line of code gives error as : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined

Here i came to know that active.url is undefined as urlHistory.getActive() has undefined values, instead it should contain current URL. I dont know why it is undefined. is there a routing problem? I have made the following settings in jqm config:

`$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;});`

Please help me out.